# Mac OSX 10.14 - Swap modifier keys fn and control

Tags: macos, keyboard, modifier-keys

I managed to make the `fn` modifier key behave as `⌘ command`. But I can't map the `⌘ command` (or `^ control`) to the `fn` handler. I need to access this handler for forward backspacing (delete), among other things.

When I try to map another modifier key to `fn`, the dropdown menu does not hold the correct option, as shown on this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJdOU.png).

How could I map the `^ control` physical key to the `fn` handler? I would like to do this natively, through GUI or command line, without installing any third-party app.